# SQL - There is already an object named 'variableName' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a recursive query which looks like below.

```
;WITH Hierachy(LevelID) 
 AS ( SELECT LevelID 
      FROM   tDDFLevel r 
      WHERE  r.LevelID IN 
           (SELECT LevelID 
            FROM   tDDFViewLevelMapping 
            WHERE  ViewID = 2 
           )  
      AND r.LevelID NOT IN (SELECT ObjectID FROM tSysTrashBin)  
      AND r.Parent = -1  UNION ALL SELECT c.LevelID 
      From tDDFLevel c 
        INNER Join Hierachy ch ON c.Parent = ch.LevelID  
                              And c.LevelID Not IN (SELECT ObjectID FROM tSysTrashBin) 
    )
```

The result from this query will always be a column of integers. What I want to do is that I want to save the result in a list of Integers so I have modified the query and now looks like:

```
declare @LevelIDs int  

 ;WITH Hierachy(LevelID) 
 AS ( SELECT LevelID 
      FROM   tDDFLevel r 
      WHERE  r.LevelID IN 
           (SELECT LevelID 
            FROM   tDDFViewLevelMapping 
            WHERE  ViewID = 2 
           )  
      AND r.LevelID NOT IN (SELECT ObjectID FROM tSysTrashBin)  
      AND r.Parent = -1  
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT c.LevelID 
      From   tDDFLevel c 
        INNER Join Hierachy ch ON c.Parent = ch.LevelID  
                              And c.LevelID Not IN (SELECT ObjectID FROM tSysTrashBin) 
    )  

 SELECT LevelID INTO LevelIDs FROM Hierachy  
 SELECT LevelID from LevelIDs
```

But, I keep getting an error which says:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 4 There is already an object named
>   'LevelIDs' in the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: `INTO` clause creates a new table. Looks like you already have a table named `LevelIDs`.

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO `

Comment: SELECT * FROM LevelIDs. What data does it contains ? If you are populating this every time you execute your SQL, then write DROP statement at last in that case. Or chk if exists then drop statement. Not sure if this works in case of Anchor queries ...

Comment: So did you check if you have a table with that name already?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that is not a table. It is a variable (list of ints) where I want to save the data. Is that possible?

Comment: This statement says otherwise: `SELECT LevelID INTO LevelIDs FROM Hierachy`, this creates a table.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ah okay, I know what you mean. But, can I assign the values to a list of Integers?

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have arrays or *lists*. The primary data type *designed* for holding multiple values is a *table*. (It also has XML and, for 2016, JSON which are also *designed* for holding multiple values, but not really well suited to the data here)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LevelID INTO LevelIDs FROM Hierachy
```

The above statement **creates** a new table whenever it is executed. If you want to store the result permanently then create a new table called `LevelIDs` and use `INSERT INTO`

```
Insert into LevelIDs(LevelID)
SELECT LevelID  FROM Hierachy
```

Else if you want to store the `LevelID` **temporarily** then create a temp which will be available only to that session. Temporary tables are created with `#` prefixed with the table name

```
Insert into #LevelIDs(LevelID)
SELECT LevelID  FROM Hierachy
```

Comment: Right! I've deleted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table variable like below.

```
DECLARE @LevelIDs TABLE(
    LevelId INT   
);
```

Then use Insert into.

```
INSERT INTO @LevelIDs
SELECT LevelID FROM Hierachy
```